# How do I get the data from a relation field?

Tags: plugin-development, field

If use the following code:

```php
$currentEntry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($entryId);
$currentContent = $currentEntry->getContent()->getAttributes();
$currentAttributes = array();

$fieldLayout = $currentEntry->getFieldLayout();
foreach ($fieldLayout->getFields() as $fieldLayoutField) {
    $field = $fieldLayoutField->getField();
    if (isset($currentContent[$field->handle])) {
        $currentAttributes[$field->handle] = $currentContent[$field->handle];
    }
}
```

It retrieves all data that I want, but I don't get the data from relation fields. If an asset or entry has been selected, I won't receive that data. The result from that field is always null.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the custom field name then it is pretty straight forward:

```
$currentEntry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($id);
$relatedEntries = $currentEntry->customFieldName;
```

Then you could either loop through each one:

```
foreach ($relatedEntries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->title;
}
```

Or simply get the data from the first one:

```
echo $relatedEntries->first()->title;
```

Remember that all related entries come back as an array even if you have specified that the user can only select 1.

Hope this helps

Comment: It was not exactly what I was looking for, but it got me in the right direction.